# x axis floats shows different values when selecting subset

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have these data:

https://easyupload.io/m/874ddl

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = np.load('dates.npy')
data = np.load('data.npy')

print(dates)
```

The dates are:

```
[[2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.]
 [2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.]
 [2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2016. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
  2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017. 2017.
...............
```

I want to plot dates vs data.

If I try matplotlib:

`plt.plot(dates, data)`

I am receiving:

[image: matplotlib 1]

If I try :

`plt.plot(dates[:, 0], data)`,

I am receiving:

[image: matplotlib_2]

You can see the values on x axis are totally different from the data.

I receive the same plot with seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(x=dates[:, 0], 
             y=data)
```

I want to use seaborn and have the correct x axis dates.

Comment: `dates[:, 0]` is `array([2016., 2016., 2016., 2016., 2016., 2016.])`. Note that if you use `plt.plot(dates[:, 0], data, marker='o')`, you'll get a single marker in the middle of the graph. My question now is: what plot do you want to get? You have 2 unique dates and only 1 unique data value. Arrays have shape (6, 48) and (6,). Can you sketch the graph you want?

Comment: @K.Cl. I want to have the first plot! A constant line with the correct x axis.

Comment: Your first command is iterating through the columns and plotting them against data. The first 5 cols have only `2016`, then `2017` appears in col 5 (`array([2016., 2016., 2016., 2016., 2016., 2017.])`), and so on, then around col 10 it's only `2017`. You'll only get a line if there's a variation in these `x` values. For example, `plt.plot(dates[:, 5], data)` will give you a line, but `plt.plot(dates[:, 4], data)` won't.

Comment: @K.Cl:Ok , I understand that. And somehow it shows incorrect axis labels. You can make it an answer,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command is iterating through the columns of `dates` and plotting them against the values in `data`. However, in many cases, there is no variation in the columns of dates, i.e., it's only 2016 or 2017 (`plt.plot(dates[:, 4], data)`. Only when there's both values a line can be traced (`plt.plot(dates[:, 5], data)`. By default, the matplotlib style doesn't have markers, so the graph looks empty (you can add `marker='o'` to your plot command to show this). Also, because there's no variation in `x`, matplotlib tries to give the graphs some limits to x, which ultimately end up being different from the limits when `x` varied.

If you want all column graphs to have the same limits, you can specify that with `plt.xlim(left=2015.7, right=2017.3)` after the plot of each individual column. Here, I put a 0.3 buffer to the left and right, but you can change this to whatever value looks better.